How to configure feauture addesim IOS 17 via whatsapp
I am currently developing a service where users can purchase products, and a QR code is sent to them via WhatsApp using Twilio. The QR code is intended for eSIM activation. However, I am encountering issues where the "Add eSIM" feature does not appear when users hold the eSIM QR code image in WhatsApp.
Here are the details:
Service Description: Users buy products, and a QR code for eSIM activation is sent to their WhatsApp via Twilio.
Problem: The "Add eSIM" feature does not appear when users hold the QR code image in WhatsApp. Even when sending the QR code as a URL, the feature does not show up.
Steps I've Tried:
Sending QR Code Image Directly: I sent the QR code image directly through Twilio, but the "Add eSIM" feature was not triggered.
Sending QR Code URL: I tried sending a URL to the QR code image, but the "Add eSIM" feature still did not appear.
Questions:
Is it possible to configure WhatsApp or Twilio to make the "Add eSIM" feature appear when sending QR codes?
What are the recommended practices for ensuring that eSIM QR codes sent via WhatsApp can be used effectively by users?
Are there any specific requirements or formats that I need to follow to make sure the QR code is recognized properly by WhatsApp or the device?
Additional Information:
The QR codes are generated and tested to ensure they are correct and functional.
I have verified that the QR code data is accurate and conforms to eSIM standards.
I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is referred to by community members as creating a minimal, reproducible example.
